# Is there a Vim plugin that records bursts of typing

Tags: vim

When you type code into vim you may at some point recall that sentence you were typing, it should be possible for vim to record those bursts of typing in between longer pauses.

Is there a Vim plugin that does something like that?

Comment: Isn't that what the `.` register and `<C-a>` in insert mode do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out my [PrevInsertComplete plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4185). It records previous insertions (delimited by leaving insert mode, not typing frequency - that would be difficult to determine, and you should leave insert mode frequently, anyway), and offers them (filtered by an optional keyword prefix) for completion.

Comment: that looks like i'm looking for, hacking this to work in frequency could be a good vimscript exersize one of those days.

Comment: That'll be tough. There's very little with regards to timing; you only have `CursorHoldI` with a fixed interval.